# Moving Up Value of bottom row if upper row is suppressed in Crystal Report C# ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I am starting a simple report which I am having some difficulty. This is part of my thesis work which was asked to be revised (Report Part). I have a working report but panel wants it that if Value of a is zero the whole row will be hidden and the lower row moves up.  I am able to hide a row using SUPPRESS function of crystal report but the problem is the lower row doesn't move up and just leaves an empty hole in the report.

Here is the report I'm getting with suppress. Can you give me an idea or steps on what's the best thing to do so that I can move the lower row up in case the upper row is suppressed.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Hi Kim, to suppress the row did you do it from the "Section expert"?

Comment: Thank you for giving me an idea. Im able to solve the issue by using section expert and suppressing the entire row. :D

Answer (score 1):

I have added multiple rows and each particular line item is on a specific row. I added formula that it will suppress the entire row if the amount is "0". Thanks for giving me an idea.

Kim

Comment: Exact! That's the way to go!